# Reproducing the phase spectrum while using np.fft.fft2 and cv2.dft. Why are the results not similar?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, fft

Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78163775/16815358) was asking about the correct way of getting magnitude and phase spectra while using `cv2.dft`.

My answer was limited to the numpy approach and then I thought that using OpenCV for this would be even nicer. I am currently trying to reproduce the same results but I am seeing significant differences in the phase spectrum.

Here are my imports:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
im = np.zeros((50, 50), dtype = np.float32) # create empty array
im[2:10, 2:10] = 255 # draw a rectangle
```

The numpy example and results:

```
imFFTNumpy = np.fft.fft2(im)
imFFTNumpyShifted = np.fft.fftshift(imFFTNumpy)
magSpectrumNumpy = np.abs(imFFTNumpyShifted)
phaseSpectrumNumpy = np.angle(imFFTNumpyShifted)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3)
ax[0].imshow(im)
ax[1].imshow(magSpectrumNumpy)
ax[2].imshow(phaseSpectrumNumpy)
plt.suptitle("Using Numpy np.fft.fft2 and np.abs/ np.angle")
```

[image: Numpy results]

The OpenCV example and results:

```
imFFTOpenCV = cv2.dft(im, flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
imFFTOpenCVShifted = np.fft.fftshift(imFFTOpenCV)
magSpectrumOpenCV, phaseSpectrumOpenCV = cv2.cartToPolar(imFFTOpenCVShifted[:,:,0], imFFTOpenCVShifted[:,:,1])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3)
ax[0].imshow(im)
ax[1].imshow(magSpectrumOpenCV)
ax[2].imshow(phaseSpectrumOpenCV)
plt.suptitle("Using OpenCV cv2.dft and cv2.cartToPolar")
```

[image: OpenCV results]

As you can see, while the magnitude spectrum looks the same (it has some expected deviations due to floating-point arithmetic), the phase spectrum looks significantly different. I dug around a bit and found out that OpenCV usually returns phase from 0 to 2π, whereas `np.angle` returns the phase from -π to +π. Subtracting π from the OpenCV phase does not correct difference though.

What could be the reason for this? Is it possible to get almost identical phase using both approaches, just like with magnitude?

Comment: If a pixel value is near zero, its phase is undefined (the value will be dictated by rounding errors). Make sure you only compare phase for pixels with a sufficient magnitude.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? Pixel from which representation?

Comment: my bet is on something being inverted. looks like the phases grow in opposite directions. maybe that IS equivalent, considering the math? sin(x) = -sin(-x+pi) etc -- I'm not in the mood to dissect exactly what your pieces of code do and what they *should* do. don't just look at the output. look at all intermediaries. and work on a smaller example, small enough that you can look at the literal numbers in the array, and one with values that you KNOW the results for. don't just slam a box down on a random location. maybe reduce the problem to 1D as well.

Comment: What I mean to say is that the values of  `phaseSpectrumNumpy` are meaningless when `magSpectrumNumpy` is small. The same is true for the OpenCV case. A small amount of noise on a complex number close to 0 can make huge changes to the phase.

Comment: rely on graphical comparison, without the support of computations, is often misleading: 1. the phase may contain also negative number and you are using `imshow` to display the image. This is nonsense because values should be between 0-255 (`uint8`) or 0-1 (`float`). So use [`cv2.normalize`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) for visualization 2. use `imshow(img, cmap='grey')` to avoid "strange" colours of a greyscale image

Comment: @cards pyplot.imshow stretches the intensities of floating-point grayscale images, it doesn’t assume any range in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `imFFTOpenCV` is a 3D array because OpenCV doesn’t understand complex numbers, `np.fft.fftshift(imFFTOpenCV)` will swap the real and complex planes. That is, the shift happens in all 3 dimensions of the array.

So when computing the phase and magnitude, you need to take this swap into account:

```py
magSpectrumOpenCV, phaseSpectrumOpenCV = cv2.cartToPolar(imFFTOpenCVShifted[:,:,1], imFFTOpenCVShifted[:,:,0])
```

Alternatively, and this is probably more readable, you could tell NumPy which axes you want shifted:

```py
imFFTOpenCVShifted = np.fft.fftshift(imFFTOpenCV, axes=(0, 1))
```

Comment: I compared the two images and the result seems to be more consistent but they are still different (tested only the 1st method). Is this due to floating point arithmetic/underlying implementations?

Comment: @cards You should get the same answer modulo 2π. “Same” means within numerical precision of the algorithms. In the FFT, rounding errors can accumulate quite strongly, different implementations can produce differences of the order of 100 or 1000 times the numerical precision of the floating-point representation used. Also, as I mentioned before, where the magnitude is close to 0, the phase is dominated by these numerical errors.

Comment: Mmm your remarks about the 2pi modulo comparison is very interesting. I compare the phases modulo 2pi and they looks much much better! Shouldn't we work then always modulo 2pi when dealing with phases or are there some drawbacks?

Comment: @cards Phase is usually computed within a specific 2π interval. It’s just that NumPy and OpenCV use a different interval. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52429073/7328782 — You need to take that into account when you’re comparing their results. For some pixels the one will say -π/4, the other will say 3π/4.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that `numpy.angle` and `cv2.phase` are not comparable because their underline implementation is different.

- [`numpy.angle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html#numpy.angle) works with a ***fix*** domain, (-π, π]
- [`cv2.phase`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga9db9ca9b4d81c3bde5677b8f64dc0137) uses [*arctan2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) which is a ***piecewise defined*** function and its output depends on the possible sign of the rise and the run. That's the reason why in OP is written *"OpenCV **usually** returns phase from 0 to 2π"*

To be able to compare the phase of a complex number with the two libraries is much easier to forget about the `numpy.angle` and just use [`numpy.arctan2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html#numpy.arctan2):

```
im = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)

# numpy
fft_np = np.fft.fft2(im)
phase_np = np.mod(np.arctan2(np.real(fft_np), np.imag(fft_np)) * 180/np.pi, 360)

# opencv
fft_cv = cv2.dft(np.float32(im), flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
phase_cv = cv2.phase(fft_cv[:,:,1], fft_cv[:,:,0], angleInDegrees=True)

# display results
print(phase_np)
print(phase_cv)
```

Output

```
[[ 90.  30. 150.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]]

[[ 90.        29.997692 150.0023  ]
 [  0.         0.         0.      ]
 [  0.         0.         0.      ]]
```

But not think to be finished yet! `numpy.arctan2` seems to return also negative angles but `cv2.phase` is always positive... so you need to use a further *modulo* operation of a full period, so either 360 or 2π, on its result. This can be done with `numpy.mod`.

You can check it out by using `[[1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0]]` in the above example.

---

Here, the final `numpy`-counter part of `cv2.phase`:

```
def phase_np(x, y, angleInDegrees=False): # angle_np2cv
    if angleInDegrees:
        return np.mod(np.arctan2(x, y) * 180/np.pi, 360)
    return np.mod(np.arctan2(x, y), 2*np.pi)
```

Also another difference could be the datatypes: `np.fft2` uses `complex128` and computations (`np.angle`, `np.arctan2`, ...) on it are usually `float64`.

---

Conclusion: [`cv2.cartToPolar`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gac5f92f48ec32cacf5275969c33ee837d) is *arctan2*-based as `cv2.phase` so the same holds.

Comment: use either `numpy.rad2deg` or its alias `numpy.degrees` for conversion of an angle in radians to degrees